# Angularjs search and display

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search function where users are able to search and navigate them to the "searchedResult" page. And that's where I display the information. I tried doing something like this, but it isn't returning me any result with no error in console either.

HTML:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="result in apiResult |orderBy:sortKey:reverse |filter:search">
          <td>{{result.NAME}}</td>
          <td>{{result.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER}}</td>
          <td>{{result.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE}}</td>
          <td>{{result.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
        </tr>
```

JS:

```
       $scope.searchFunction = function() {
          searchLayer.clearLayers();
          for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.allTheme.length; i++) {
              if ($scope.selected == $scope.allTheme[i].THEMENAME)
              {
                  $scope.selectedTheme = $scope.allTheme[i].QUERYNAME;
                  apiURL = "url";

                      $http.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.apiResult = response.data.SrchResults;
                        $scope.apiResult.splice(0,1);
                      })
                      $window.location.href = "#!/searchedResult";
              }

          }

       }
```

Comment: When you call `$window.location.href = "#!/searchedResult";` you navigate to the new `searchedResult` state. But if you save the data inside the `$scope.apiResult` of this controller, this variable is not accessible in the other controller, if it's not a child scope of this one (which should not be because you change the url). There are a lot of ways for sharing data between controllers, but in this case maybe the best solution would be to use a service shared between these two controllers.

Comment: They are both in the same controller

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by "they are both in the same controller". By the way, two things: 1) when you make the get request, if you redirect not inside the `then` but after, you will redirect before the data gets fetched. 
2) When you change the location, the controller starts up again, and the `$scope` gets init again, so the previous value of `apiResult` is not there anymore. 
Add a console log on init of that $scope, printing the scope, and you should see that there is not `apiResult` after you execute  the relocation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @quirimmo